# Nonexistence of conjugate points $\Rightarrow$ a geodesic is minimizing

Tags: soft-question, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, global-analysis

**Motivation:** I am trying to prove a certian geodesic is minimizing. The only generic tool I know for doing that is the fact the a gedoesic is minimizing as long as it stays in a normal neighbourhood of it's starting point. (But this is too crude for my needs...)

**Question:**

It's well known that geodesics do not minimize length past conjugate points.

Are there any conditions which imply the converse holds?

,i.e certain Riemannian manifolds where a geodesic with no conjugate points is always length minimizing?

I am interested specifically in non-compact matrix groups with left invariant metrics (In particular complete manifolds).

**To clarify, the manifolds I am interested in are not simply connected, and in particular [it's not true that every geodesic is globally minimizing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1530064/104576) ($exp_p$ is not a diffeomorphism from $T_pM$ onto $M$**)

The geodesics I am interested in do not intersect themselves and are not dense.

---

A counter example can be given by the cylinder $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ (considered as a Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$):
There are no conjugate points along any geodesic, but of course there are closed geodesics which stop minimizing at some point...

Comment: Might I ask one stupid question, if there are conjugate points $p,~q$ along one geodesic, then can we  say that this geomdesic is not minimal on the $p,~q$ segment part ?

Comment: No, we can't. Example: $S^2, p=\text{north pole }, q=\text{south pole}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p,q \in M$ and let $pq$ be a geodesic connecting them. $pq$ will be minimizing if and only if its intersection with the cut locus of $p$ is empty. The cut locus of $p$ [is made of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_locus_%28Riemannian_manifold%29#Characterization): (1) the conjugate points of $p$ and (2) those points $r$ such that there are multiple minimizing geodesics from $p$ to $r$. Since, by assumption, $pq$ contains no point conjugate to $p$, if we manage to also eliminate the points of type (2) from it we are done. A sufficient condition that guarantees the absence of those points (globally from $M$, not just from $pq$) is the [Cartan-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), that has the following [consequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170964/the-number-of-geodesics-of-a-complete-riemann-manifold-with-non-positive-section): if $M$ is connected, simply-connected, complete, with sectional curvature $\le 0$, then each two points are connected by a *unique* minimizing geodesic (note that this smells of the [Hopf-Rinow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem), but this one does not guarantee uniqueness, it only guarantees existence).

To conclude: if $M$ is connected, simply-connected, complete, with sectional curvature $\le 0$, and $pq$ contains no conjugate point of $p$ (or $q$), then it is minimizing.

Comment: Thanks. However, Hadamard's theorem implies $exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism on $M$, so $M$ can be considered as a normal neighbourhood, so it follows that every gedoesic in this case is globally minimizing. (From the well known fact that geodesic is minimizing as long as it stays in a normal neighbourhood), and (like I wrote in the question) this is not applicable for my case. I am actually interested in Lie groups which are not simply connected. (Think on matrix groups...)

Comment: So I guess I have no choice but to produce an argument which rules out existence of multiple minimizing geodesics.